# Is there a way to search an object in a python list?

Tags: python

I have a list with objects, i.e.:

```
[{"id":"1", "name": "name1"}, {"id":"2", "name": "nam2"}, {"id":"1", "name": "name3"}]
```

I need to find the count of objects of the list that have "id":"1", in this example: 2

Comment: @Herohtar altough this question was tagged with JS, the title specifically asks about Python

Comment: @DeepSpace Maybe so. I assumed he was using JavaScript with a (JSON) list that was returned from a Python script.

Comment: thanks to all, i am new, i will improve my researches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to filter the data you need. For example:

```
# Data:
l=[{"id":"1", "name": "name1"}, {"id":"2", "name": "nam2"}, {"id":"1", "name": "name3"}]
print(len([x for x in l if x['id']=='1'])) # Result: 2
#         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#         This is the key part: you filter the list according to a condition
#         (in this case: x['id']=='1').
#         If all you need is the number of entries for which the condition
#         holds, printing the length of the resulting list will be enough.
```

Answer (score 2):

It was nice if `collections.Counter` had a `key` argument like `sorted` and `itertools.groupby` have, unfortunately it does not.

I'd use `collections.defaultdict` to serve as a counter. As a bonus we will get a counter of all the different IDs:

```
from collections import defaultdict


li = [{"id":"1", "name": "name1"}, {"id":"2", "name": "nam2"}, {"id":"1", "name": "name3"}]

counter = defaultdict(int)

for d in li:
    counter[d['id']] += 1

print(counter['1'])
# 2
print(counter['2'])
# 1
```

**UPDATE**

I seem to have overlooked the fact that you can still use `collections.Counter` as @RoadRunner mentioned in the comments:

```
from collections import Counter


li = [{"id":"1", "name": "name1"}, {"id":"2", "name": "nam2"}, {"id":"1", "name": "name3"}]

print(Counter(d['id'] for d in li))
# Counter({'1': 2, '2': 1})
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but couldn't we still use `collections.Counter(x['id'] for x in li)`? I've unfortunately reached my daily vote limit and can't upvote this(I'll make sure I do tomorrow). Downvoter must be having a bad day.

Comment: Why bother importing `Counter`? Just run a list comp for matches and take the length? That said, I don't know why this was downvoted. I guess it's more extensible using a Counter

Comment: @roganjosh because tomorrow OP will want to count another ID

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but you could *also* just use a `Counter` object using the same exact loop, `for d in li: counter[d['id']] += 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a different take on this problem:

```
import operator

a = [{'id': '1', 'name': 'name1'},
 {'id': '2', 'name': 'nam2'},
 {'id': '1', 'name': 'name3'}]

sum(operator.countOf(i, '1') for i in map(operator.itemgetter('id'), a))
```